# What should we replace setEulerZYX with in the btQuaternion class (this method is now deprecated)?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are using a Sparkfun Razor IMU, and it produces Euler angles in yaw,pitch,roll order.  We need the setEulerZYX method to put this into a quaternion, but compiling this produces a warning that it is deprecated.  I cannot find an equivalent function, do anyone have any suggestions for replacement?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174843/what-should-we-replace-seteulerzyx-with-in-the-btquaternion-class-(this-method-is-now-deprecated)?/) by [pdrews](https://answers.ros.org/users/18984/pdrews/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-06-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-06-24**:
I use transform_datatypes.h to implement OMPL. The transform_datatypes.h includes createIdentityQuaternion() and createQuaternionFromRPY() and so on. There is the transform_datatypes.h in /opt/ros/***/include/tf/. It's my pleasure if my comment is useful for you.

**Comment by [pdrews](https://answers.ros.org/users/18984/pdrews/) on 2014-06-24**:
Unfortunately, this has the same problem as Dan's answer.  All of these methods are rotations around fixed angles, instead of sequential Euler angle rotations.  I agree that Euler angle implementation can be ambiguous, but euler rotations and fixed angle rotations don't seem to be equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do that with a [tf::Quaternion](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Quaternion.html)

```
tf::Quaternion q;
q.setRPY(from_degrees(roll), from_degrees(pitch), from_degrees(yaw));
```

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pdrews](https://answers.ros.org/users/18984/pdrews/) on 2014-06-24**:
We are actually using tf::Quaternion, which is mostly derived from the bullet btQuaternion class.  The problem is that q.setRPY and q.setEulerZYX are not equivalent.  setRPY takes rotations around a fixed set of axes.  setEulerZYX uses rotations relative to a frame that stays attached to the body (see the wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles).